# How to change entry box user input

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter-entry

I want to be able to change the user input of an **apostrophe** `(')` to this **backquote symbol** `` (`) `` because I'm using the user input to ask a MySQL database for the information the user asks for, and MySQL strings either start or end with apostrophe. This means that if a user types one in and python tries to do anything with it, there ends up being an error so I just want to be able to change the `(')` to a `` (`) `` when the user types it into the entry box and to show it in the entry box but I am having trouble with this. I don't want to change anything to the MySQL database so I just want python to fix this issue itself.

```
from tkinter import *  # allows for the use of tkinter GUI

win = Tk()  # creates the tkinter window
win.title("test")  # sets the name of the window
win.geometry("300x200")  # sets the size of the window
win.resizable(False, False)  # prevents the window from being resized

def changeto(e):
    nsearchentry.insert(-1,'hi')
    print(nsearchentry)

nsearchentry = Entry(win, width=20, font=('Arial', 12))  # sets up the nsearch entry box and its parameters
nsearchentry.pack()  # moves the nsearchentry box to its location
nsearchentry.bind("'", changeto)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"....python tries to do anything with it"_: As long as you are not evaluating it and it remains a string, there is no issue on the apostrophe.

Comment: that's my mistake, I meant to say mysql has issues with it, but this isn't a mysql question so I forgot to say that. Either way, I still want to figure out how to do this.

Comment: @neo_codex I am guessing that you use `nsearchentry.get()`. Just replace it with `nsearchentry.get().replace("'", "\`")`

Comment: Wow, it was that simple, thanks @TheLizzard.

Comment: Are you wanting to change the character as the user types it, or replace it at the moment you use it? For the latter, are you familiar with python's built-in [replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) function?

Comment: @BryanOakley both work, but I'll just use the replace function since I just tested it and it worked.

Comment: I think this should not cause any issue as long as you are santizing your input. Can you share your mysql code too

Comment: @TheLizzard your comment posted as answer and another trick as well. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to convert inside (User won't know) then at last (Just before you want to use that data) use `.replace()`.
Example code is :

```
data=nsearchentry.get()
data=data.replace("'","`")
#Here you want to use that data
```

Or if you want it in real-time then try this :

```
def ch():
    x=nsearchentry.get()
    nsearchentry.delete(0,END) 
    # We have to delete to make sure same text won't overwrite again
    nsearchentry.insert(0,x.replace("'","`"))

nsearchentry.bind("'", lambda e: win.after(1,ch)) 
# 1 Millisecond delay just to make sure that ' is written in Entry
```

Trick Idea :

```
def ch():
    x=nsearchentry.get()
    nsearchentry.delete(0,END)
    nsearchentry.insert(0,x[0:-1]+"`")
    # Remove ' and add `

nsearchentry.bind("'", lambda e: win.after(1,ch))
```

Comment: While this might solve the problem temporarily, I think the real issue for this problem is not parameterizing SQL input, which is leading to this error. I refuse to believe that you cannot input a string that has `'` in it into MySQL

Comment: @CoolCloud I know what MySQL is but I don't know syntax and other things..... I had this question from tkinter part. And additionally, there is no tag of MySQL Yeah I know OP mentioned but ...  so, I believe I am not wrong.